# Why use both the spread operator and destructuring assignment in a function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I keep coming across this syntax and I'm having trouble understanding exactly what it's doing:

```
export class SomeClass extends SomeParent {
    constructor(...[configuration]) {
        // lines of code that reference only "configuration"
    }
}
```

Playing around in the Node REPL I can't find a difference between:

```
function foo(...[bar]) { console.log(bar); console.log(arguments) }
```

...and...

```
function foo(bar) { console.log(bar); console.log(arguments) }
```

...so what is it for?

Comment: spread is not an operator

Comment: …and it's not even spread syntax

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty pointless indeed. You'll need to ask the author of the code what they intended with this, they should at least have left a comment.

However, there actually is a minuscule difference: rest parameters do not count for the function's arity. So `(function(bar){}).length` is `1`, whereas `(function(...[bar]){}).length` is `0`.